# SAP Crystal Report Viewer "NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i successfully installed SAP Crystal Reports from here: https://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 (Support Pack 15). I drag and dropped a CrystalReportViewer to my Form and added a new CrystalReport. I added two date fields to the report document. But if i start my application, i just see an empty window although the preview in visual studio shows the report viewer. If i try to make it visible via:

```
crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```

I get "NullReferenceException" on "crystalReportViewer1"? I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and .NET 4.0.

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/crystalreportx53jkyu6gv.png

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/crystalreportviyxsm9io0wl.png

Comment: Did you actually read my question?

Comment: Yes we read it. Your `crystalReportViewer1` is obviously `null` (not set to an instance). _why_ it is `null` you can figure out with the help of the linked question.

Comment: But i dragged the object into my viewport, why should it be null? I can also change its properties in the viewport. I just noticed, if i drag a button it is also null. What the heck is going on here? Also, none of the cases described in the linked article correspond to my case.